# Switching word wrap automatically on in Komodo Edit when opening file

Tags: file-io, configuration, automation, word-wrap, komodoedit

I use Komodo Edit 8.5 and i want to set the word wrap automatically on, when i'm opening a file. Unfortunately i can't find this setting in "Edit > Preferences". Can you help me?
And exists there a possiblity to change this settings in the 'prefs.xml'-file?

Answer (score 1):

The word wrap preferences are located in the following hierarchy:

- Edit|Preferences|Editor|Smart Editing

If you want to set it using [prefs.xml](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/blob/master/src/prefs/prefs.p.xml), here is the setting:

- <long id="editAutoWrapColumn">80</long>

I would advice against editing prefs.xml directly, in this case the Pref UI should suffice but if you wish to manually modify a pref it's safer to use the API:

```
ko.prefs.setBooleanPref()
```

or

```
ko.prefs.setStringPref()
```

You can use a macro or the [Extension Developer addon](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/komodo-developer-extension) to access the API.

**References**

- [Komodo Source: XML Files](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=extension%3Axml+user%3AKomodo+repo%3AKomodoEdit&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

Comment: I would advice against editing prefs.xml directly, in this case the Pref UI should suffice but if you wish to manually modify a pref it's safer to use the API: ko.prefs.setBooleanPref() or ko.prefs.setStringPref(). You can use a macro or the Extension Developer addon (http://community.activestate.com/xpi/komodo-developer-extension) to access the API.